# Routing network from database created by osm2pgsql

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, osm2pgsql

I created my PostGIS database by osm2pgsql tool and now I want create network suitable for routing. (I could not use directly osm2pgrouting because I need street names e.g. and so on).

For this network I this is the best solution use pgr_createTopology(). But now I could not use  function for shortest path pgr_dijkstra() because table "planet_osm_lines" not contains column which will be represented cost of edge, which is required for this function.

Can you tell me ho to resolve this?

My table planet_osm_line's script:

```
CREATE TABLE public.planet_osm_line
(
    osm_id bigint,
    access text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "addr:housename" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "addr:housenumber" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "addr:interpolation" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    admin_level text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    aerialway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    aeroway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    amenity text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    area text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    barrier text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    bicycle text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    brand text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    bridge text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    boundary text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    building text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    construction text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    covered text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    culvert text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    cutting text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    denomination text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    disused text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    embankment text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    foot text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "generator:source" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    harbour text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    highway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    historic text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    horse text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    intermittent text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    junction text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    landuse text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    layer text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    leisure text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    lock text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    man_made text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    military text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    motorcar text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    name text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "natural" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    office text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    oneway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    operator text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    place text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    population text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    power text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    power_source text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    public_transport text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    railway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    ref text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    religion text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    route text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    service text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    shop text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    sport text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    surface text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    toll text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    tourism text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    "tower:type" text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    tracktype text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    tunnel text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    water text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    waterway text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    wetland text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    width text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    wood text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    z_order integer,
    way_area real,
    way "public.geometry"(230633732)
)
```

Comment: Try to create a new column and popolate it with ST_Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any column or combination of attributes as costs.
However, it's better to use `osm2pgrouting` to import OSM data, because it does a few pre-processing steps, that `osm2psql` doesn't do, and which are necessary to get a correct routing network.

If you need more attributes than the ones provided by `osm2pgrouting`, you can join your OSM tables, imported with `osm2psql`, with the network table `ways` using the attribute `osm_id`.

Comment: So I could import my osm file into postgis twice to same database but with different tools ?

Comment: Yes, with the current release this is a way to get access to all OSM attributes. The next major release will allow the import of all attributes using osm2pgrouting only, but I can't tell when this will be available.

Comment: okey thanks :) could you tell me if tha osm2pgsql is the best tool for getting "pure" osm data or could I use someting else?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column to your table that contains the cost for each row.

To add a new column you would do:

```
ALTER TABLE public.planet_osm_line
ADD COLUMN cost_dist double precision;
```

And then to populate the new column you would do:

```
UPDATE public.planet_osm_line
SET cost_dist = ST_Length(planet_osm_line.way);
```

Where `ST_Length` is the PostGIS function that takes your geometry column (`way`) as input and calculates the length of it. The output is in the same measurements as your projection.

Answer (score 0):

I think osm2pgrouting is the better tool. When you use osm2pgsql to import the osm data to database, the relation tag information was ignored, pgr_createTopology() only use the geometry relation between nodes, but osm2pgrouting use the relation tag information.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain a bit what you mean by the 'relation'? Thank you!

Comment: 'relation' is a tag's key(or name) in osm planet_osm_line table.